# Accurately detecting socket sending failures in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am writing an Android app that initializes a `DatagramSocket` to connect to a server and then uses an infinite loop to periodically (e.g. every 5 seconds) send packets of data. The sending code is below:

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
try {
    socket.send(packet);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Log failure and return
}
// Log success
```

Now, I can afford to lose a packet every once in a while. But I would like to be able to detect if the server becomes unavailable (e.g. crashes) while I am connected, in which case I would like to hold on to the messages I send (to send them at another time). Originally I thought that an exception will be thrown every time I try to send a packet through this socket, and hence would be able to deal with storing the messages in my `catch` block. In fact it partially works. I model server crashes by just switching off the server, and I start getting exceptions with message `sendto failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` when I send a packet. The problem is, not every attempt to send throws an exception, but only every even attempt - so my log looks like

> Success, Error, Success, Error, ...

What happens in my understanding is that on the first attempt to send a packet after the server becomes unavailable, the packet gets sent, the socket doesn't wait to see if there is an error message, and a success is logged. Then on the next attempt, the socket tries to send a packet, sees the previous error message, and throws an exception without sending the packet, hence leading to an error being logged. However, because the packet was not sent, there will be again no exception thrown on the subsequent attempt to send a packet. This is a hypothesis I drew after seeing my log, so I could be mistaken in my reasoning here.

My question is, is there any way to make sure the exception is thrown every time as long as the server is unavailable? Or is there any other way to detect that the other end of the socket has silently disconnected? I tried checking for `socket.isConnected()` inside my loop, but it always returns `true`.

Comment: @MisterSmith Why is the server code relevant? My intention is to handle the case where the server is unavailable.

Comment: Because I guess your server spawns a thread per incoming connection.

Comment: @MisterSmith I do not create any threads in my server code. The server runs within a single thread with a socket listening to one port, and tries to read packets from the socket in an infinite loop. It doesn't send any data back to the clients.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "server not available", is it a condition you set?

Comment: @MisterSmith Yes, I need to be able to buffer the packets that were rejected to be able to retransmit them later. The way I am testing this is I just switch off my server.

Comment: Then, when you turn off the server, the whole socket connection should drop, not only `send` throwing an exception. That is the part I don't understand in your question. Do you re-open the socket connection each time?

Comment: @MisterSmith No no, the socket on the client is initialized before the infinite loop and never changes throughout the loop. My question is exactly about how I can detect the connection drop - if I check for `socket.isConnected()` in the loop, it always returns `true`, even after the server is switched off. The `send` also does not always throw the exception, as I explain in the question...

Comment: I added more details to the question based on this discussion.

Comment: What if you test the socket status explicitly before attempting to send your packet? Maybe you can do something using the `Socket` methods: `isConnected` and `isClosed`; and, possibly with `isInputShutdown` and `isOutputShutdown`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DatagramSocket` are by definition connection-less -- here's a good page about the [differences between UDP and TCP](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/udp-datagram-sockets.html) for posterity.  That you are getting any errors at all indicates to me that you are sending to a server on your local network which is not responding to arps -- either that our your default gateway is going away which is less likely.  That any of your `send` messages are returning errors is *very* OS and network dependent and IMO should not be relied upon.  It also means that if you put a router between you and the server then *none* of the `send` methods would return error I believe.

If you need to see if the server is up and has received your messages then I would recommend that you add code to the server to send an acknowledgement back to the client.  You wouldn't want the client to send and wait for the ack for each packet but maybe send X packets and then wait for the ack for all X or have a wait table with a retransmit thread or something.

Of course, once you start down that road, you may want to consider using [Jgroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) or switching to TCP/IP.  :-)

Comment: True. I tried entering some random IP address and port number for my app, and expectedly received no error messages. So this is the expected behavior then. Indeed, I was getting the errors I talk about because I was running the server on the same machine as the Android emulator with the app! I suppose the only way to overcome this without switching to TCP (I really don't need all the overhead) is to make sure the server is always up.